# what is the difference between creating custom view and using jetpack compose in android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-jetpack-compose

I am new to android programming. I am finishing my first android app that is coded in java and I want to learn kotlin after that.

I am really interested in creating my own view (custom view) to have a better app.
I want to know if there is any difference between using jetpack compose and creating custom view...

can jetpack compose be used instead of creating custom views??

Thanks!

Comment: Compose is a completely separate view system. It's not officially released yet. This is maybe an awkward time to get into Android development because it's clear Google is going to push Compose very heavily once it is officially released, but since it's not yet, you kind of need to know the original view system right now. I don't know if I'd recommend a beginner to start with Compose yet because you'll be fighting with the early pre-release quirks when you aren't fully familiar with Android yet.

Comment: so you mean it is better not to use it because it is not officially released??

Comment: is it ok to continue creating custom views for making android apps??

Comment: It’s a matter of how much time you want to put in. In my opinion, you should wait before learning compose. It will be easier to learn when it’s more complete and stable, and by then you’ll be much more fluent in Kotlin. There will be a some years of overlap where Android developers will need to understand both because you’ll be working with both old and new libraries/examples, etc. so you might as well learn traditional Views now. They won’t be deprecated any time in the near future because Compose is Kotlin-only and brand new. Thousands of code libraries are based on traditional views.

Comment: such a great answer thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Tenfour04 said :

Compose is a completely separate view system. It's not officially released yet. This is maybe an awkward time to get into Android development because it's clear Google is going to push Compose very heavily once it is officially released, but since it's not yet, you kind of need to know the original view system right now. I don't know if I'd recommend a beginner to start with Compose yet because you'll be fighting with the early pre-release quirks when you aren't fully familiar with Android yet. – Tenfour04 Feb 1 at 20:13